# Custom Phases not being added to phaseConfigList

Tags: xml, optaplanner

I'm trying to make a custom construction heuristics phase.  The phase config extends AbstractPhaseConfig, XStream can't figure out that it should be added to the phaseConfigList.  It is trying to assign the class to its own class variable.  The LocalSearchPhaseConfig works perfectly.

XML

```
<solver>
    <customConstructionHeuristic></customConstructionHeuristic>
    <localSearch></localSearch>
</solver>
```

My Class

```
@XStreamAlias("customConstructionHeuristic")
public class CustomConstructionHeuristicPhaseConfig extends PhaseConfig<CustomConstructionHeuristicPhaseConfig> {
    @Override
    public ConstructionHeuristicPhase buildPhase(int phaseIndex, HeuristicConfigPolicy solverConfigPolicy, BestSolutionRecaller 
            bestSolutionRecaller, Termination solverTermination) {
        return null;
}
```

}

Local Search Phase Class from Optaplanner

```
@XStreamAlias("localSearch")
public class LocalSearchPhaseConfig extends PhaseConfig<LocalSearchPhaseConfig> {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you're business focused:**

Why not use a **Custom phase** instead?

```
  <customPhase>
    <customPhaseCommandClass>org.optaplanner.examples.machinereassignment.solver.solution.initializer.ToOriginalMachineSolutionInitializer</customPhaseCommandClass>
  </customPhase>
  <localSearch/>
```

That won't get you into trouble when upgrading to a new version, extending `AbstractPhaseConfig` might.

**If you're academic focused:**

Yes, hack it. That's good. Consider contributing it back later :) Call this so your CustomConstructionHeuristicPhaseConfig class is recognized by XStream:

```
XStreamXmlSolverFactory.addXStreamAnnotations(CustomConstructionHeuristicPhaseConfig.class);
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, I'll definitely take a look.

In particular what I want to do is inject a custom value selector into the current construction heuristics.  Is there an easy way to do that?